# Wait for a keypress in an application with no console or window

Tags: c, windows

I need a way to get a keypress from an application which has no console or GUI windows.  I'm currently polling using `GetAsyncKeyState` but this uses unnecessary amounts of CPU time.

Is there a better solution?

Note: Since the application does not have a console, I cannot use `getchar` or other such console only functions.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  Is this a console, GUI or service app?

Comment: Any. Please note i already said it can't be console only.

Comment: Unless you're going to have a key press interrupt, you'll need to poll (i.e. use a loop).

Comment: It;s not that simple.  Serice apps have no UI and run on a desktop with no direct UI inputs.  GUI apps receive WM_KEY* messages.  Sorry, but it's unclear what you are asking for...

Comment: A service isn't interactive, so waiting for keyboard input is non-sensical; a GUI would have a message pump, so that also makes no sense. A web page is sent an entire request...so really, the only place this question makes sense is the one you rejected (console only).

Comment: It's a console app that has no console. It currently uses `GetAsyncKeyState` with a `while` loop and `sleep`, but this is way to roundabout for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [low level hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) so it receive events from the kernel. That means you will receive these events even if it's for another application.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbd = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    switch(nCode){
        case HC_ACTION:
            switch(wParam){
                case WM_KEYUP:
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                    printf("[%i %s %c]\r\n", kbd->time,
                            wParam == WM_KEYUP ? "Up" : "Down",
                            kbd->vkCode);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    HHOOK kbdHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {

    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(kbdHook);
    return 1;
}
```